# Remove default table styles in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, css, table

I inserted a default table style in SharePoint and I would like to write some CSS rules to remove the other table styles. The default style should be the one which is added by me, the others must be removed.

So far, I tried this way but doesn't seem to be working:

[image]

```
#TableStyle1-Menu {
 display: none;
}
```

How shall I write the CSS rule to work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

The working CSS rule to remove default table styles which are not used in Sharepoint ribbon is:

```
ul.ms-cui-menusection-items li.ms-cui-menusection-items #TableStyle1-Menu {
  display: none;
}
```